# how would I write this using haml

Tags: haml

I'm trying to use the fonts.com webfont loader. But the page I'm working on was created in haml. I'm relatively new to haml so having trouble how to translate this script tag with the loader into the new syntax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    WebFont.load({

        monotype: {

            projectId: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'///this is your Fonts.com Web Fonts projectId



        }

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:javascript` filter

```
:javascript
  WebFont.load({
      monotype: {
            projectId: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
  });
```